What is the meaning of multiplying a submatrix of left-eigenvectors matrix by the corresponding submatrix of right-eigenvectors matrix?
Given an eigendecomposition $ \mathbf{A} = \mathbf{Q} \mathbf{\Lambda} \mathbf{Q}^{-1} $, we know that $ \mathbf{A} = \sum_{i} \mathbf{Q}_{*, i} \mathbf{\Lambda}_{i, i} (\mathbf{Q}^{-1})_{i, *} $.
Now, if we have a susbet of eigenvector indices $I$, then what is the meaning of $ \mathbf{M} = \sum_{i \in I} \mathbf{Q}_{*, i} (\mathbf{Q}^{-1})_{i, *} $?
I'm using this calculation as part of an algorithm that factorizes multiplication of an input matrix by $\mathbf{A}$ by partitioning of the set of eigenvector indices to subsets $I_1, \ldots, I_k$, then calculating $\mathbf{M}$ for each of them, followed by multiplying the input matrix by each of those resulting matrices. My algorithm works for the task it is intended to solve. However, I don't understand what this calculation of $\mathbf{M}$ actually means mathematically.
My thesis advisor told me that, for each subset $I$, $\mathbf{M}$ is supposed to serve as a low-rank approximation of $\mathbf{A}$. He mentioned the Eckart-Young-Mirsky theorem, but I fail to see how it relates to this calculation, since the theorem deals with SVD rather than ED.

$Q_{*,i}^{-1}$ doesn't make any sense, since it would be the inverse of a vector.

As far as I know, the standard order of operations in matrix notation is first inverse and then indexing. Does the inverse have to be in parentheses?

Note that if $A$ is a symmetric (but possibly singular or indefinite) matrix, then you can easily convert $Q$ and $\Lambda$ into an SVD using the absolute value of $\Lambda$ as $S$, taking $U=Q$, and then using $\pm$ the columns of $Q$ as $V$, depending on the signs of the eigenvalues.

$\mathbf{A}$ in general is not symmetric in my case.

What makes you think $A$ has an eigenvalue decomposition?

That's a given.

@Moon Could you say more about what this algorithm does? Perhaps you could point me to a reference.

@BenGrossmann Given a guarantee that all eigenvalues are either ~(1 + 0i) or with a norm smaller than 1, the algorithm calculates M for the subset I that contains all indices of ~(1 + 0i) eigenvalues and another M for the complementary subset of indices. The matrix A is a Koopman matrix. Therefore, the first M is an image of the input series that contains the time-invariant features of the series, and the second M is an image of the input series that contains the time-variant features of the series. It works, but I don't understand how the math enables it.

@BenGrossmann It is based on the work of Berman et al..

@Moon You can think of multiplying $A$ by $M$ as applying a sort of "mask" that changes the update behavior so that, except within the span of the eigenspaces of interest, the dynamics are stationary; the undesirable eigenvalues are being "zeroed out".

@Moon Actually, rather than the dynamics within the bad subspaces being made stationary, the internal state is approximated with its projection onto the span of the good subspaces and the dynamics are calculated from there.

@BenGrossmann Do you mean that projecting the input onto M for each subset I eliminates the uninteresting features (of all other than this specific subset of eigenvalues), while preserving the original space, so any M for a given subset I acts as a mask on the inputs?

Yeah I think we’re on the same page

The matrix $M$ is sometimes referred to as a "spectral projection", which is to say that it is an oblique projection (at least, typically oblique) onto a sum of eigenspaces of $A$ that commutes with $A$ (i.e. that satisfies $AM = MA$).

What are these kinds of projections generally used for?

@Moon They come up a lot in functional analysis and perturbation theory over linear operators, but I can't think of any practical usage cases

What about mode decomposition?
